# Rich snippets for responsive layout in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, product-page, rich-snippets

Assuming below structure in product view page, should I add the rich snippet tag `itemprop="name"` for both views, as  Google does not crawl css with diaply:none.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="product-view">
        .
        .
        .
        <!-- small view -->
        <div class="product-name" class="visible-xs">                       
                        <h1 itemprop="name" ><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        <!-- large view -->
        <div class="product-name" class="visible-lg">                       
                        <h1 itemprop="name" ><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inresting question. Another was World be to plane it in JSON within head.